# Timezone randomly changes in Django admin

Tags: python, django, timezone, uwsgi, ubuntu-server

There are two instances of a Django project deployed using uWSGI server with NGINX proxy on Ubuntu server 14.04. In settings I have:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'  # UTC +03.00
USE_TZ = True
```

On one instance Dates and Times are displayed in correct time zone. On another instance time zone keeps changing between +03.00 and +12.00 and I didn't manage to notice any pattern in that.

I checked:

- Ubuntu time zone with `timedatectl status` (the same on both servers)
- PostgreSQL timezone (the same on both servers)
- uWSGI and NGINX setting are kept in VCS, so they are the same as well (although doesn't seem to have anything time zone related)

The only difference I can think of is that the properly working instance is on Azure, while the problematic one is physically hosted in UTC +03.00 (local cloud provider). However, other Django projects hosted there work properly.

What else can I check to isolate and solve this problem?

Comment: Hey Den Kasyanov, did you figure out what was causing this?